# Lorentz Factor is just the SINE function Opposite/Hypotenuse

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

Has anyone noticed that the Lorentz Factor used to calculate the  relativistic length compression and time dilation for an object moving through space, can be written as the SINE function… Opposite over Hypotenuse?

And the inverse function for Time Dilation is then simply Hypotenuse/Opposite?

[image: Lorentz as the SINE function]

Comment: Or cosine, or tan ..

Comment: The sine of... what?

Answer (score 1):

This is crystal clear if you let the triangle sides be lengths instead of speeds. Let the hypotenuse be $c\Delta t$, the horizontal side $v\Delta t$. The vertical side is then $A=\Delta t\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$ according to Pythagoras' theorem. But for an observer $O'$ who travels at speed $v$ to the right, $A=c\Delta t'$ since light speed is invariant. So $\Delta t'=\Delta t\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the underlying reason why [Pythagoras' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) (and its higher dimensional analogs) keep popping up  is because Nature is well-described by a [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) on a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold). If we lived in a [Finsler manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold), this would no longer be true.